# MATLAB VLFeat mex error : 'mt' is not recognized

Tags: matlab, sdk, mex, vlfeat

I'm trying to setup vlfeat 0.9.20 with MATLAB R2015a, on Windows 8 64 bit.

I installed Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1, and ran `mex -setup`, it seems to find the SDK properly.

But when I run `vl_compile;` I get the following error :

```
vl_compile: assuming that Visual C++ is the active compiler
vl_compile: compiling for PCWIN64 (64 bit)
MEX C:\Users\Name\Documents\MATLAB\Tools\vlfeat-0.9.20\toolbox\aib\vl_aib.c
Building with 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C)'.
Error using mex
'mt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Error in vl_compile (line 140)
    mex(cmd{:}) ;
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks !

Comment: See: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/166600

Comment: @rayryeng thanks. I did see this before posting. However, the solution proposed there (changing mexopts.bat) , I think, does not apply anymore. I checked the new versions (mex_C_win64.xml etc) , but I couldn't find a relevant field.

Comment: mt is the manifest tool, and it should be in the SDK. Edit the `mex` command to include the `-v` switch to see where it is looking

Answer (score 3):

For an almost identical setup (as far as versions go) I had the same problem.

When installing Windows SDK 7.1, you have to make sure to select the option to install "Tools" for either native or .NET development.

[image: Install options for Windows SDK 7.1]

In my case, I had done a minimum install of headers, the compilers and the redistributable, as I was previously only using it for building Python packages.